# finding the commen objects in two arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8

Need to find the common objects between to arraylist. Both of them are `VarList` type which is the simple POJO class. My comparison return all the elements inside the database list , Need to have a common elements (which as you can see they are objects) between two arraylists and add the them into the new list.

**VarList class**

```
public class VarList {
    private int number;
    private int age;
    private String name;
    public VarList(int number, int age, String name) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**my solution which has a problem**

```
//database arraylist
        ArrayList<VarList> database=new ArrayList<VarList>();
        database.add(new VarList(105,19,"b"));
        database.add(new VarList(101,18,"c"));
        database.add(new VarList(106,54,"database"));
//object array list        
        ArrayList<VarList> object=new ArrayList<VarList>();
        object.add(new VarList(105,19,"b"));
        database.add(new VarList(106,54,"database"));


        List<VarList> resultList = new ArrayList<VarList>();
        for(VarList user1 : database) {
            for(VarList user2 : object) {
                if(user1.getName().equals(user2.getName())) {
                    resultList.add(user2);
                }
                System.out.println(resultList);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem your implementation is having? Not great with Java so IDK if there's a better way, but this seems reasonable.

Comment: “which has a problem” is not a useful problem description. Further, it’s not clear what “the database list” is supposed to mean. And you didn’t define “common elements”; your code only compares name strings, so is “equal name” intended to be the definition of “common element”?

Answer (score 1):

## Override `equals` & `hashCode`

You need to define [overrides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) of [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashcode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods in your `VarList` class. Your class inherits these methods from [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html).

Also, think harder about naming things.  The `VarList` class is not a list, it is an element in your list. Surely it has an actual descriptive name.  The second `ArrayList` you declare is named 'object'?!?  Please don't name things object, ever.  Call it testList or something.

Finally, your `System.out` is inside the `resultList` loop, so its output is likely to confuse you.  Or maybe that was intentional.  Just realize that it's going to output it once for every element in `resultList`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing your own for loop to compare the elements of 2 ArrayList, you could use `retainAll(list)` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) of the Collection class.

Here is the sample Usage:

SimplePojo.java

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class SimplePojo {

  private String name;
  private int age;

  public SimplePojo(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "SimplePojo{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", age=" + age + '}';
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    SimplePojo that = (SimplePojo) o;
    return age == that.age && Objects.equals(name, that.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, age);
  }
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListCommonElements {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SimplePojo> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(new SimplePojo("Dave",49));
    list1.add(new SimplePojo("Smith",40));
    list1.add(new SimplePojo("Johnson",32));
    
    System.out.println("List 1: " +list1.toString());

    List<SimplePojo> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(new SimplePojo("Dave",49));
    list2.add(new SimplePojo("Smith",40));
    list2.add(new SimplePojo("Steve",32));
    
    System.out.println("List2: "+list2.toString());

    list1.retainAll(list2);

    System.out.println("Common ELements: " + list1.toString());
  }
}
```

Notice How I am overriding `equals` and `hashCode` method (You can autogenerate it if using IntelliJ ).

The reason to do it is your list is not of primitive type, so you need to tell what does equal mean to you (so you can get common elements ) and in the current implementation, I am saying that if both name and age are the same then only I would call 2 Object equal.